# pass Github secrets to a docker github action

Tags: docker, github, github-actions, github-secret, docker-aws

Hi my devoted and beloved developers!

Today I face trouble trying to transmit GitHub secrets to a docker GitHub action in order to use this variable in the container. I already have defined for the project the secret `what_a_secret` for the key `CHUT`.

Here is what I currently have:

```yaml
name: Continious Delivery
on: [push]
jobs:
  myjob:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
      - name: Docker Run Action
        uses: addnab/docker-run-action@v3
        env:
          CHUT: ${{ secrets.CHUT }}
        with:
          image: amazon/aws-glue-libs:glue_libs_1.0.0_image_01
          options:
            --env CHUT=$CHUT
            -v ${{ github.workspace }}:/workspace
          run:
            echo CHUT=$CHUT
```

This just print `CHUT=$CHUT` instead of `CHUT=what_a_secret`.

I also tried to do something like this:

```yaml
            --env CHUT=${{ secrets.CHUT }}
```

And this:

```yaml
          run:
            echo CHUT=${{ secrets.CHUT }}
```

But the lasts solution returns nothing at all.

Your help would be warmly welcomed

**EDIT:** the documentation "[Configure GitHub Actions](https://docs.docker.com/ci-cd/github-actions/)" do not work to pass environment variables to a container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final anwswer is: I made my code cleaner and did this :

```yaml
name: Continious Delivery
on: [push]
jobs:
  myjob:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
      - name: Docker Run Action
        uses: addnab/docker-run-action@v3
        with:
          image: amazon/aws-glue-libs:glue_libs_1.0.0_image_01
          options:
            --e CHUT=${{ secrets.CHUT }}
            -v ${{ github.workspace }}:/workspace
          run:
            echo "CHUT=$CHUT"
```

output is `CHUT=***` because Github is smart enough to not print a secret in the terminal. But the docker read the secret correctly.

Comment: How do you do the `--secret` flag though? You ahve to mount it to a file...